# How is this 'overpowered being' voice effect made?

Tags: voice-manipulation

There is a certain effect I've heard multiple times, that I can only describe as 'overpowered baddie in his final form'. I can't quite place how it's done, but I think it's some kind of pitch modulation.

Here are some examples:

Darkseid in Justice league war

Son of Osiris in Age of Mythology

Poww in Bleach

**How is this effect made?**

Comment: The 1st & 3rd are too long to scan through to find what you mean. Please provide proper timestamps. The 2nd one could probably be done with any VST plugin that claims to do "dalek" voices [usually done with a ring-mod], perhaps with an extra mod on the pitch shift.

Comment: @Tetsujin The relevant parts are interspersed throughout the videos. A big chunk of voice can be heard at 1:36 on the third video. Also It doesn't sound close to being a dalek ring mod.

Answer (score 0):

Pitch and formant shifting, along with voice acting.  Take a look at Little AlterBoy or a million other tools that do this.